# Ajax call html page contain JQuery (draw canvas), not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, canvas

I have a main html page 'pageA' has ajax call sub html page 'pageB' that contain javascript to draw canvases display

```
<script src="/static/mysite/js/gauge.min.js"></script>
```

But now, pageA result contain only 'text_test' without canvas

Called pageB directly display full data I need

and ajax code in pageA to call pageB is following:

```
function refreshTab(deviceID, tabName, pageName){
    $.ajax({
        url: '/dsesite/'+deviceID+'/'+pageName+'/',    
        success: function(data) {
        $(tabName).html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

in developer tool display url of 'gauge.min.js' when called pageB directly is:

```
"GET /static/mysite/js/gauge.min.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
```

but when called pageA it return:

```
"GET /static/mysite/js/gauge.min.js?_=1435989780270 HTTP/1.1" 200 12412
```

I tried to import 'gauge.min.js' from only pageA, only pageB and both pages but not work

Comment: How do you initialize canvas?

Comment: I implemented
    <canvas id="gauge1"data-type="canv-gauge"
                data-onready="setInterval( function() { Gauge.Collection.get('gauge1').setValue(Math.random() * 600);}, 1000);"
></canvas>